# Laravel - Can the route and model have different names

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5

My laravel application has a model - Video. It is the main model so the route was named **videos**. But after the development I discovered that there is a folder on the production server named **videos**

So now rewriting the url to include index.php in .htaccess does not work.

I cannot change the name of videos folder which is already present. 
I cannot change the db table name either. I don't want to do that, its too much work.
Is there a way to change the route name to something else like lvideos or vvideos?
I tried changing it in routes but it seems there are other places where I have to change it. It throws me an error in the controller.
Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

I don't want to give the link with index.php to the users

Thank you.

Comment: You'll have to change the route and anywhere the route is referenced.

Comment: "It throws me an error in the controller", what kinda error exactly?

Comment: What error are you getting when running the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to change the route anywhere it is referenced.

In the future if you think a route might change, you could use named routes and then reference the route name anywhere you need to use it.

For example:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'videos'], function() {
    Route::get('/', [
        'uses' => 'VideosController@index',
        'as'   => 'videos.index',
    ]);
    Route::get('{id}', [
        'uses' => 'VideosController@show',
        'as'   => 'videos.show',
    ]);
});
```

Then everywhere you use these routes you use the name, for example in a view:

```
<a href="{{ route('videos.index') }}">Videos</a>
```

The link will still work even if you change the route to `Route::group(['prefix => 'iVideos']);` Even though the route changed, the name did not.